# phpmyadmin open in 8080 after varnish setup with APACHE 2.4

Tags: phpmyadmin, varnish, apache2.4

My setup :

Apache listening on 8080

Varnish 5 listing on port  80

phpmyadmin protected  with htpassword
mydomain/phpmyadmin shows prompt for password after giving htpassword it shows phpmyadmin login page after entering database password it agin prompt for htpassword but with 8080 port then it opens the phpmyadmin databse login.

so my http://mydomain/phpmyadmin 
is becoming http://mydomain:8080/phpmyadmin

i tried several thing but not working since a 24 hr .

Can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions to the problem is to have your Apache and Varnish BOTH listen on port 80. This is actually possible: simply bind the Apache to localhost interface only (Listen 127.0.0.1), and keep Varnish on the public interface.

This will make sure that the redirect retains desired port.